# How can I fix my alignment?

Tags: css, html

Here's my fiddle

```css
 html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #cbox {
            border: 1px black solid;
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 95%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;

        }
        .message {
            min-height: 50px;
            max-height: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 98.9%;
            border: 1px black solid;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }
        #snd-msg {
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 3%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .pimg {
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
            border: 1px black dashed;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
        .username {
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            text-decoration: underline;

        }
        .date {
            position: absolute;
            color: gray;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            right: 0;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="cbox">
        <div class="message" name="tink" id="mid">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="pimg">
             <span class="date">13:00 - 07/23/1993</span>
            <span class="msg"><span class="username">tink</span><span class="text">HI</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="snd-msg" />
</div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to align everything center to the profile image. But, everything I try is a no go. It wont move no matter what I set. I've tried margins but it just does an overflow thing I checked with developer tools. Run the snippet and you'll see what I mean I hope you can help me out. If there's anything else you need let me know and I'll provide it the best I can

Comment: Are you looking to center it vertically or horizontaly?

Comment: by everything I meant the `.msg` class  and vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Use of `box-sizing: border-box;` for remove horizontal scrollbar.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**2)** Use of `vertical-align: middle;` for aligment elements.

```
.pimg {
      vertical-align: middle;<-------Added
      //more code..
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: none;
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#cbox {
   border: 1px black solid;
    width: 100.0%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.message {
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 98.9%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#snd-msg {
    width: 100.0%;
    height: 3%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pimg {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border: 1px black dashed;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.username {
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-decoration: underline;
 }

.date {
    position: absolute;
    color: gray;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="cbox">
        <div class="message" name="tink" id="mid">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="pimg">
             <span class="date">13:00 - 07/23/1993</span>
            <span class="msg"><span class="username">tink</span><span class="text">HI</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="snd-msg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `vertical-align: middle;` to the image in order to set the text right next to it to display at the middle of the image:

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #cbox {
            border: 1px black solid;
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 95%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;

        }
        .message {
            min-height: 50px;
            max-height: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 98.9%;
            border: 1px black solid;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }
        #snd-msg {
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 3%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .pimg {
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
            border: 1px black dashed;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .username {
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            text-decoration: underline;

        }
        .date {
            position: absolute;
            color: gray;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            right: 0;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="cbox">
        <div class="message" name="tink" id="mid">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxIREhUREBMVFRUXFxcWFxcXFxgWFxUdFxgXFxoYHRcYHSggGBolGxgYITEhJSkrLi4uGB8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0lHyYtLS0wLS8tLzItLS0uLS0tLy0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAOEA4QMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABgcBBAUDAgj/xABKEAABAwIDBQQGBgcFCAIDAAABAAIDBBEFEiEGBzFBURMiYXEUMoGRobEjQlJyc8EVMzVikrLRFzR0gqIkNkNUk8Lh8FOzFiVj/8QAGwEBAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQGAQMFAgf/xAA9EQABAwIDBQQIBQMEAwEAAAABAAIDBBEFEiEGEzFBUSIyYXEUM4GRobHB0RYjNOHwFTVCJFJy8VOCkmL/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/ALxREREREREREREREREWCbalFry1jG87+S5NTjdHBoXXPQara2F7uS1J8UsL2DR9pxAHvOi479o55Tlpovfr8B91t3DR3io5iO3tHESJKyIHo05j/pusBuN1Gt8o9g/f4oTC1R+q3tYe3hJM/wAmG3xXoYBiEnrJj/8AR+68+kxjgFz5N8dEOEU5/gHzK9DZR570ix6YOiwzfHRHjDOP4D8is/hNw4SJ6YOi36Xe3h7uL52ebCfksfh6sj9XMfeQs+lMPELvYdvAopbBlZHfo85T/qCx6NjUHdfmHjr89VnPA7kpLTYrmGYZXt+0wgj3i4QY5WwG1RD7R/Cs7lju6VtxV7Hc7ea6VNj9HNoTlPj91rdTvC2Qb8F2WuDhdpuFptZZXpEREREREREREREREREREREREREREREJWCQBcotOevA0bqfgq7XbRQw9iEZnfD91IZTk6u0UI2n3h0lLcSy9o8f8OKzj7eQ9pXMZRYniZzSnK33D3c/ivZkii4cVBZdu8Vrzlw6n7Jh4Py53eeZwyj2ArpNwnDKAXqHXPj9lq3ssndC+Yt3FfVnPX1byTyL3PI95sPYF4l2lpYBlp4/gAPgsilc7vFd6g3T0LP1hfIfE2HuC5M21NW/uWHsW0UkY4rtU+weHM4U0Z8wD81Afjde/jIfYtogj6L3bgNGJo4GwRNzse5t2jvFuUZR42cT7F2dny+skeZ5CbW0udb/ZaaizAA0LYfszSWLZKeLMDr3QvW0LzSyN3DyCeQJSnGcHMFoVGwuHP40zB5ABcNmNVzOEhW4wRnkuJXbqaJ/6svYfA3HuXQh2orGd6x9i1upIzwUfm3aVtMc9DVOBHDK90Z/0kLrw7UQSaTMt8VpNG4d0pDtvi9AQ2uhE7B9Zzcr7fiMGvtHtUt1HheIC7LX8NCvGeaLipxsxvIo6ohrZTBIfqS2AJ8HeqVzX4NW0Jz0jzbp+y2iojk0eFO4MRGgeLeI4Fb6XaCzt3Vtyu68v2+KOp9LsN1vNcDqNVY2Pa9uZpuFHII0KyvawiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIvKedrBc+5Qa7EIaNmaQ+Q5le2Rl50UQ2u2ygo2Zqh9vsxN1e/yH5nRVEyV+NSZGaM+A8zzP8spP5cIueKq+bF8VxtxZTA09MdDY2zD95/F/k2w812G0+HYO3NIc0nx9g5fNabyzHTQKTbO7r6Sns+cdvJx73qA+DOB8zdcWu2lqZuzF2G+HH3rfHSsbx1U4hhawWY0NHQCyrrnucbuN1IsvReVlERYRF4VlHHMMsrQ4A3HIg9QRqD5LdBUSwOzxOIPgsOaHCxX1T07Y25WCw8yfidSk08kzs8huepWQ0AWC9FqWURERF5zQteMr2hw6EAhemuc03abJZQnaPdnSVF3QjsXnp6pPkrBQ7R1MFmydpvjxUaSlY7UaKJw4hi2COyPvPTX9R13Mt+67jGfLTwVmZNh+LMyutf4qIWywG/JWbsbttT1wvTvLZB60D7Bw8vtDxC5EtDW4U/eU5zM5j+f9qQ2SOYWdxU1patr+Gh6LuYdisNYLDR3MH+arTJE5nkthdRakRERERERERERERERERFrVlWGaDV3yXFxbGGUTcrdXngOniftzW6KIv15Kqtvd4nYO9Gox21U42JtmbHflYes/wDd4Dn0PDoMIlrnGrrXWZx6E/Zv8C2STBnYZxXK2Z3dSTv9LxZ7pHu73Zk3/jPP7o081txDaBkLfR6EAAc/t91iOmJOaRWbBC1jQ1jQ0DQAaAKoPe55zONypoFl6LyiIiIiwiIsrKwiIiIiIiLCIiLKLKLznha9pa9oc08QbEeS9Me5hzNNisEXVZbWbuSx3pWGucx7TmyA2I8WkK34XtGdIqrUdfuoU1J/kxbuw+8Zz3ikxL6Ocd1k3qh54WkH1XdHDQ+HOZiODNl/1VGbO46c1riqCOxIrco63N3X6O+a94XjBld6PUaSD4/v816lht2m8FuqwKOiIiIiIiIiIiIiItatqgwWHrH4eK4uMYs2iZlbq88B08T/ADVboos58FTu3+28r5f0fh13zPOV8jdS2/1G/vdXcvlyMLwoOBrq86cQDz8T9BzXuabXdxrrbBbBMoW9tN9JUu4v4hl+LW3+LuJUDF8ZlrTu4gRGPj5/ZbYYRHqeKmmU9CuBu3dCt9whaVjI4ckuEynoUyO6JcJlPQrO7d0KXCwQsFpHELKwvTI3v7ouhIHFLLL4Xs7wIQEHggC8BpPAImU9CvW7d0PuS4TKfFN27ofclwsWPRYDHHks3CAFA0ngEusFYII4osgHoshjjwCXCwsLKf8AvFe2RPf3RdYJA4qG7d7Cx1rTJGAyYDQ8n+B813cLxaagdkkBydOnko80DZRccVHthNtZaaUYdiZIAOWKZ3Fh4BrieLDydy+VjxHDYsQiFRTntcQVFildE7K9XVQVebuu9bl4rXhGKOkPo1RpIPj+/wA17mit2m8FvKwqOiIiIiIiIiIvKpmDBc+zxUHEK5lHCZHewdSvcbC82VSbzttXxH0Olu6plsCW6mMO0AH755DkNel6zhOHurZHV1WeyNdedvoP2UiaTdjIzitzd3sW2gj7WazqmQd93HIDrkafmeZUDG8YNY/dx6Rjh4+J+gXuCHILniovtXg+MPqpHUrpRET3QJMo9y7eGYlh8VKxkpGbnotE0UjnktUPgrMTfUijbUSmYuyBvakC9r2zcOAVhvS7nf5Rltfhy8lF7ebLdTnYbC8Wiq2vrXSGHJICHSZhcsOXTzVexLE8PkpXsiIzHhopUUMocC5Q6KuxKpq5KemqJS7PKWt7QtFmE3Av4cl3AKaClbLI0WDRfRR+255A6ldP9B4//wDJN/1VC/q+FdR/8rZuJlOtn6yooMMfJX5nSsc93edmJBtlF+ir+JGDEayOOmOh04WUqIOiYS5V5Q0eK406SdspDGutq9zGNJ1DWtbxsFY5Z6HCI2x5ePQXJ8SSojWyTkkFfAr8TwOdoke5zTqWFxfHIOY73A26LdDLR4pEcov7NQvLhJC7VTDbeCvq3QT4a6QRPiDzlflBz2I8zxXFoJKPDnSw1Fr5tNL6KTIHygOaoBi1ZidLIIZ6iZrzaw7UnibDyVhpn0lSzeRAEeSiPEjDYqR4bgeONmidI+UsEjC76W4Lbgnz0XOmxXDQ1zdL6/481ubDNoUxHGqgY4yJs8gjNVEMgccpDntuLdCtlBFGcOzZRfK48PNeZXES28Qtne/is8NTGIZpIwWG4a4gHXwUDZiJj4HlwB1WyscQ4WUr3X7RmtpA2R2aaHuPJOr2/Ud49D5Ln7S4eI3idg0PFbaSXMMpUO2rxeoZjMcTJpGxmWC7Q4hpu8A6eK7GCQxnDcxaL9rl4LTUOIlt5KdbwNqxh8N2gOleS2Np4A9T4Aaqr4VhZrqgg6MHH7e1S5pt2zxVY0GCYvijTU9q7KScpfI5gd91jeV9L+HNW6fEcPw0iC2o5AXt5lQmxSyjMvvD9osQwaoEdU5z4ye/G9xeC3m5jjqHBbt3R4pASwX+YXm8kLrFT7brZOLEYBPBbtMoex32wRcA+KqtDXSYXVGF+rL/AMKmyRCZlxxXL3YbYPLxhtaSJmXELyfWy/8ADJP1reqefDjx7WMYcJ2Crpj2hrpzUenlLTkerkoqnONeI4hS8JxEVkXa744j6pNFkPgtldZaUREREREJWCQBcooPt/tU2jgdMdT6sTftOPD+vkFRnl+M1+Rvq2/LmfMqbpDHc8VB91ezj5HOxWsBMkhJizdDxlt48G+AvzCkbRYg2NooafQAdq3wb9StVNGXHeOVnKnqchRFROC/7wR/4k/yOX08f2r/ANFyj64+avOX1T5H5L5i3iF1V+dcMxt9DiElTGwSOa+YZTcA5iRy1X1k07aijbE82BaPkuNnLZCR1Klv9sNT/wAnH/E9cn8MUfUrf6W/opnW58UwkPDQ180WfKCbA3IsL+Sr0giw3EwG90WUoXliKqrZzaqtwgvh7MFhdd0cgIF7WuHDhornUUlLiLATqORC57XvhKlsO8TDqxzBiFM6MjQP/WRtv1HrAeOq5Dtn5YATSSEX5KQKpru8FZtFExkbGxW7MNGTKbty8RbwsqXWNmbM4Td7mp7MpHZ4KlN6/wC0m+TP5le9mv0J8z8lzqv1gV3xnut+635BUSt/UP8ANdGPuhUZiP7fi/xcH87V9Ew7+1j/AIO+RXLm9f7R81ub7z/tMf3HfMKDsr6l/wDyWys7zVhs36FxYSWtTzBuYDgGSBpP8LjfyupzLYhSPif3gSPcdPeF4P5UgI4Lz20Fsdi/FpyOhBeCD7QvGDsLMPLDxGce5JzeUHyXzvlqC+vEd9GsAH+c6n4Ba9mow2mc7q4/BZq3dsDwVwZo6SnbpaOKNos3kGtHAKk1DXVFa5vNzl0WWaxQPGNtMDqy11Q2Z5aLC8J0+KstNgeIUwIilAuoj6iJ/eCnuByROp4XU9xEWAxg6EN5acrKtYpFLHUObM7M7mVLiILeyFAd6eyxIFfTC0jCC7Lx0Ojh4jiu7s7iuR3o0p0PBRqqC4zt4qW7udrhXU4lJHbR2ZM3r0eB0d81txOB+G1Qq4u6eI+axC4SsyHirCY8EAjgVaoZWysEjDodVGIINivpbFhERERaOKVGVtr8ePgFXNoq7cwiFned8v3UinZc3KoirzY5ivZC/osBN7cC0HvHzcRlHgFiANwfDd4fWO+fIezj5ry476Ww4BXDGwNAa0WAAAA4ADQBUN7i9xceJU8Cy+l5WVgoiorBv94I/wDEn+Ry+oD+1f8AouUfXHzV5y8D5H5L5g3iuqqI2Inijxhzqh7GR3qATIWtZre1y7RfUKyJ8mHZIwS7K21lyYyBKSeqtn9I4V/zFF/1Yv6ql/0zFf8Aa74qfvoeoXnje0UdPSOqKLsZ2xmxbG8OaPC7L2PNeqbCpHVTY6sFubrxR0wyEs1suZsjtHS4ux4qIoWTNd+rLgS5pAs4ZtTrcH2Lo4lhM1EA+kLrc1qhnbJo9RDevgFFStY6AtZK52sbXAm3NxbyHiujgFVXSuc2cHKBxIWqqZGBdvFT7dmX/oul7S98rrX+zndk9mWy4G0rmGuIbyAv5qTSX3eqrTev+0m+TP5lZNmv0R8z8lFq/WBXfHwb91vyColb69/mV0Y+6FRuIft+L/FwfztX0TDv7YP+DvkVy5vX+0fNbe/D+8x/hu/JQdlvUP8A+S2VnfapjvJ2f9KomyNH0kTGuHUjKNFysPr/AEbEntd3XGy3SRZ4RZVLhle+asojJqY3U8QPMtZIMt/EAgewK6ujayOTLzzH2kfsoAcS4XUs314c5tUyoHB7ct+hHBcDZmoBjfFzDiVJrGahysDAMcpsUpAO0aHlgbNGXBr2ECx0OpaeTguNieGVNNVb+Jtxe4UiGVr2ZSqr3jUdBTvZBRZS8XMrmuzBulgy40vzPSyseCyV0odJVaDkCLe1RKgRDRit7Yf9nUn4LPkqhtB+uep9N6sLsysDgWu1BFj4gritJabjit9lTk5dgWKCUX9HkNnjkWOOv+ZvrDyPVfRaGZmKUJjfxtY/dcuRphkuOCvjCagHuggggOaRwIOoPtGqgYFUOhlfRS8RqPqPqt07Q4B4XTVpUVERFgm2pRVnvY2j9HpXlps+TuM8AefuuVSqJhxPEzK7ut+Q4e9S5Duorc1rbqcB9FoWyPFpZ7Su6hp/Vt/h183KPtLXb+p3TT2Wae3ms0seVt+qmaralIiLBRFAKDd8+PEG15lByy9pkt4EWv5FWv8AETRSejhn+NrqJ6Nd+a6nzxcEeCqo4qYqpq90r5HveagDM5zrW4XJKukW1TGMazd8AAoBo7m914/2PO/5gfwr3+LW/wDj+Kx6D4qZbIbIijppaWVwkbI7MdLcrLjYpjRq3sewZS1SIoMgIUPxndG4vLqaVoaTcNcPV8F16XasBoEzdeoWh9Fr2SvrA90dnh1XKHNBuWN0zeBPRKvau7SIG69TyWWUVj2irUhjaxoY0ANaAABwAGlvYqa97nuLnakqcBbQKC7XbAvrar0gShoAaALX4G6sWF462ig3WS6jS028dmup2zQAdAB7hZcCeTeSF9uJUhosLKBVG797sQbXdqBlmZLkt9hwda/sVkp9oWw0u4yciL+aivpcz81177d7DOxGVsglDA1pba173WjCcbbQxuaW3ubr3NT7wg3U0YzuBrte6Gn2AAriTzbyZ0g0ubre1tm2VcDdflqxURygNbM2UMt0cHWv7FaI9qLQCNzLm1r+yyiGj7WYFTrHsIirInRTC4PA8x4hVumrJKebex6FSnRhzcpVWV26KbP9FKwt5ZhqFcItq4svbYb+CgmidfQrr0+6ljaZ8faAzPLbyEaMaDezRyueJUJ+1DnTh+XsC+nU+PktgoxlseKnuAUBpqaGnJv2bAy/W3NV/Eav0ud0trXUmJmRtl0LqCtiiW8rAhV0bi0XfGM7fZxXZwKu9Fqhfuu0K0VEedi8Nz+0BnpBE4/S0xDdeJYfV92o9i7u0ELqeZlZFxB/nvUaldmaWFWux4IBHA6qzQytljEjeBF1oIsbFfS2LC166TKw+Oi5GN1O4o3EcToPatsLcz1Q21X/AOzxmKjGsUR7/Sw7z/hYf5lCwhoocMdUHidfoPuszfmShvRW/wCSob3Fzi481PAsEXlZREWERFlZREWERERLoiwiKrt7uP1VLNCKaeSIOY4uDDYEi1lddlqeKWKQvaDqOI81ArHlpFl09uMYqIcLp54pnslc2LM8HvHMG3v5rzRQRuxd7XNFtdFl7iIAVz90+2U1RLJSVkrpHOHaQveRe7fWZ7u8PIqZtBhbHU+8iaAW9Oi100xzWK2t7uNVNK2E00z4i4kOyG19DoubstBHK6TO0HQcVurHFoFlMNmKl8lHTySOLnuiaXOJ1J6nxXJxxjW1rw0WC3U+sYXTuuSt6XREuiJdEREWboiIiXWEWHC4seB0I/JZGmqwqgwZ36LxzsybRTkxnp9Ie4fY+38RX0WFwxHC7Hjb4hcwjdTK+MLku0tPEFaNnKgvpzE7iw29i2VLbOv1W6rEo64u0tYI43OJ0a0uPuVP2keZZ4qdvn79B9VLpxYFyqLc1Smaerr36lzsrSeryXu+Fh7FJ2lkEFJHTt8PgLLVSjM8uVqqiLoIiLCIiysoiLCIiIiIsXRERFTm/L9dB+G/8le9kvVSeY+q51b3mrrbxP2NTfdh+TV4oP7zJ7V6k/ThQUUb6amosSg0dneHEfaZIcvvborCJw+pkpn9AR5EaqLlswPClO9rEmVVLR1MfqyXPkbd4eYK5OD0hpauaPlofit1Q/PG0qxtjv7hS/gsVVx79c9Tab1YXXXHW9LoiXRERFlERERYRERERVXvsw4gRVLNHA5bjkeI9xsrlsnUdp8J81ArW6BytbZXExURwzj/AI0TX+0i5HvuvVGPRcXfFydf7/dZd24Qeikatqiqu97lf2dHOQdSAwe3T+qpwHpOOa8G/QfdSicsC0N0lF2WGRO5yufJ7M2UfBqibUzZqsM6BeqRtmKYqsqUsIiLKyiIsIiIiIiwiIiIsrKpzfl+ug+4/wDJXrZL1UnmPqubXd5q6+8T9jU33Yfk1eKD+8ye1epP04XvsZhDavAmwOHEzFvgRI7VasaqnUuJslbyAXqnZnhsVVeIVEscRoZBpHM57b8WkjK4DwOh87q2RCOUiobzFvZx+CgOuBkK/QGx39wpfwWL5zj365661N6sLsLjreiIiIsoiIiLCIiIiLKLCiu8yi7XD5erRmHsXYwGbdVzPHT3rRUNvGV57nK/Ph8QJ1ikez2XuPgSu9jg3GIQzDqL/wA8lopu1GWq0larqMqa351NqZrftSX92qqOADeYjNJ4u+JUmp0iA8lLdkqfsqGkj6U8V/MsDj8SVw8cfnrpD42W+AflhdVchbkWVlERYREREREREsV6DSeSLCwsoiKCbw9ipsRkjdE9rQxhGtyTc/8AhWPBMXjoWOa5pJJ5KLUQGQg34Lc2o2XlqqCGka5rXMDA5x4dwC9h7F5psXjir31Lmmx5I6AujyXXS2JwZ9FSMppHBzmuebjQHM4uHzUTGMQZXT7xosLWWyCLdtsVFttt3bqyftoHtZcd6+tz1XTwnaBtJDupQTbgtM9LvHXCm+A0boKaGBxBdGwMJHAkLiYjVNqqh0rRYFSImZG2W8oK2IiLKIiIsgLIBPBYWFhEWEWbFespPJLovKLRxyHPTysPNjvkpFK/JMx3QheXC7SFAdxc30FTEfqyMd722/JXPaxl42PUCjOpCuT0pbf6r4r1ulSe/d/chHi4/AqHsprLK7+cVmr4NVoUjMscbekbB7mgKsYkb1ch8VKiHYCrLehtZWUdSxlNMWNLLkWB106hWnZqignp3OkaCbqJVPc1wsuLLtFtAwZnGUAC+sbeHG/BdURYUXZOzfgtF5rXUu3abdyV7n01U1oma3Ox7RlEgBs4FvJwuDccdemvHx7BYoot/CLW4hSKaoLjlcoxtNtfiTK59LSzOtmDWMDWk3PIXC6OF0NIaJskjBwuStU0jxIQFrT7SY/GC95lAGpvG2w+C3sjwl5yty3K8kzjUhTXdrts7EA+GoDRPGA7M0ZRI0mxOXk4G1/MLh4/g0UEe/hFhzCkU05ccrl57xtujQgQ09jO4XzHURt625kqLgWCCrO9m7g5dT9l7qZ8nZHFQhhx6VnpAkqLEZh3g026hvRWc1OFwv3XZv5KIGTkZlId328KZ8wosQOZzjljlIyuDvsP6g9eqi4rgkE8RlhFja+nNe4KhzTlcpxtXtDHQQOmk1PBrQdXnkPeqdh+HSVk+6bp1PRT5ZAxuYqqYcexvES6Snc9rAbWjsxjf3bnVxAV43GGYa0Mfa/jqT4rnZppTcL3wvb3EcPnEWIZpYz6zXgZwPtMeOnTmvcmH0OIRXjA8wsCWSJ1nKytrsTdHQyVNM+x7PPG8dCLgqm0dFu8RbBKLi6nySXiLh0VVYdtdjdQ0vgke8NIa4tYzQkXA4dFdp6XDoLb1rRfquc18ruC9Tt5jFI9pqe8D9SVgAcOYDhqD4ry2gw6paRGAfJZMsrDqrOxHG+0w41tMS3NEZGcy021HjYqnOw4U+Itgdq249yn73NEXDoqqw7bLG5wTBI+QNtmysabX4X0V1mo8OhtvGtF+q57Xyu4LZO0O0H/APX/AKbf6KPkwnqxevz+hVgY9tU6iw+KeUZp3RRjKdLyFozXA4WNyfJVlmHR12JPZGbMB4jp4KYZDHEC7iq7p6rHq1vpEckuQ3y5SGNNtO63pdWZ0mF0R3JsCPC59qhgTSdoLr7FbfVUdS2ixIl7XOyB7haSJx4XI9Zp4LXiGE0tZBvIQAbXBCzFO9jsrlIt5e2b6BrYacDt3/WOojaOJtzceA9qruBYM2qe583dbpbqfspVTPkAA4lQhzdoC30gyTgWzesAbfdVmFXhTH7oZenDT3qJknIzKV7tNu5auQ0dZYzBpdHJbKX5fWY4faA1v4Fc3HcGh3JqIRa2p8ltppzfK5T+qF2OH7p+RVJZo4ea6BVX7lDaeuZ0y/zvCvu0mtEw+XyC5tL6wq286pu9KnWVR79292E+LvkVZ9k9Hyj+cVFrODVadO67GHqxh97QqxiQtVyDxKlRdwKld9397Z+EfyVz2T/TO/5KDWd4Kw3bbYa2AZquI2jALQS5xOUCwaBqVxqnAq6SpdIxuhPVSGTsDbFV1unHaYqZGAhgZM4+Ado0HzJCsmNuEWHFrjrYD2qHT6y3C1sbrGQ42JpSQxkzHOIBJAHHQale8MYX4a1o4kFJjaa6sDE95mFuikDZJHktIDRC8FxPK7gAPaVW2bMVgkDrtGvVSzVssovuXwqQ1EtY5pbH2bmNPJxe4EgdQA34rrbS1kcdN6ODdxt7h181opGEuzclyHQitx1scurXTgEdWxtLy3yOU+9Tqb/T4XdnEMJ9pXh/bm1V7L5kdV1bKid69GKavEsXdLgJBbk5pBv719G2anMtHldyNvYuZVttJcc1u76MSdJLAzl2Qlt4vaP/AD71nAqdrHTOH+6yxUuuGhWlgFJHR0cUYs1scTS4+JGZzjbmSSVTMUc+orn9SbBT4QGxhRXaatwSvLDPVx3Ze1i4cevdXboKDFqIERNGq0SPhk7y3NoWQtwV7aZ/aQiIiN1ybtFwBrqtEfpH9WjNRbNccF6dl3Jy8LKF7q9qqShjnbVSOYXvY5tmPfcBtj6oNlYMcw2auawRW06qLTTNj4r73mbV0te2KKjzyPzXvkc3joGgO1JJ8FowTCJ6F7nyuFrdfivVTO2QABS+LDX02BmGTR4hcXD7Jdc2XFnrGVOLMczgHAfFb2sLITfoq53fbZx4aJe0hfL2mW2VzW2y+atmKYYK5oYXWsVChm3ZuplHvigJA9Dl1IH6xnM26Lh/hJv/AJD7lI9N8Ftb5MMfLTMfGC4RuuQNdCOPxUPZ6aOnq3xOPHQXWyqaXxghRzZDej6JBHTVFOXtjGVr43Br8o4AtdoSPMLuYlgEVZIZQ6zio0VSWCxUiw9+DYrUCVrnCoNnBkg7N926jLxa436ErmSUmJ4fBlicCwdFva+KR13DVcHfNh8raiKpAJblte17Fpvqt+zFUx0b4nHtXuvFYwghwW/hG+GMtDaumeDYAvhIcDpa+R1rewr1WbMRyuL43WJWI6sgWIXb2RocJqJvS6F+aZhLiDdsjcwLTdh5WJFxcLn4iMUpYDG8gstbRbot091xxUzqD3HfdPyVTZ3gpaq7csP9orz5f/Y9X3aM2oWDy+QXOpfWFW1lKpe7Kn3VZb9ae8LD0eR79FaNnvy66aPxPwKiVWsYKnGzdR2lHSyfap4SfPs2g/G64WOR5K6QeKkU5/LCqPfaf9rj/CP5K1bJ/pnf8lDrO8F34d0lO4Nd20li1rraX1APRQqnaaaGV0eQaGy2Mo2uANypnsxszT0DC2BurrZnHVzrdT0F+CrlfiU9a4GU6DgOQUqOJsY0VQ43SMmxsQyC7HzMa4XtcHx5K+4a4twxrm8Q0rmzC81ipftFuzo46eWSLM1zWlwu4ngq9SbRVTqhrH2IJtwUp9IzLcLS3HYnI70inc4ljWskYCdGkkh1ugOmi6m1MLPRw+2t+K1Ubjmso3iU36PxoTyA5WTCQ9SxwyuI6mxJU/Dy2qw4NHNtvatUt2TXV7xSNe0PjcHMcMzXNNw4HW4IXzqppJYJCxzTouo17XC4VFbyasV2IiGA57FsII1BcTY2PMDn5FX/AACA0lDnl0v2vYubUuzyWauhvow0slhePV7IR3+6AB8lp2dq2y70c811mqYW5SrH2cxCPEaBhjcLmMRyAaujeGgOBHxHUEKv4vRy0tZvQ27SbhS4Hh8dlVG8LZmlw8MZFI58zzctJ9Vo5kcrnQe3orNg2IVVaXOkbZo+J/ZQqiJkY0Oql8f+7jfwXfNy5dV/e2eYW9v6cqN7sNk6avindUAlzHsDSHEaFtyLLpY9iM9GGOiPG91ppoWyd5a28bZiPDnxPpnObm1Gpu0jUEHkUwLE5a5rxKBolTC2OxarIra50+DdtIbufTXcepsQT8FX54mx4w1rf9wUppJgJ8FCdzmEwVLagTxtfl7PLm5ceC7+0Mk7I2mEm9+Si0oaScysYbH0P/wR/BVP0vE+rlOyRdAtbbPa2PDgztoXytk07rm8uRzcVtwzCHVj3Z3Frhr4rzNMIwLLVptm8OxOnjqmQgCRt9CMzDwLTb6wOik1VRX4ZNu2uJb4ry1scrbkKrduMCbhlXG2neSbCRuveYQ7T3/krTg9c+ugLpW2sbeahTxiN3ZVl7T7eQU0jaaqp3yZmMcXXbl7wF7gjkq9S4J6U580cmWziNFKfPks0jktvEd3uH1Azsjy5gCHMOhB1B0UI4riFHIYySQOoXvcxSC9lWOC0rqHG4YYXl2WdkZtza/R7Tbj3Tf2eCuAnFVh5lkFrtJ+Cg5cktmq8sVlDIZHcgx3yXzKFmaVrR1XWJsLqudxcd46qU/WewfAu/NXTat2WJjFAoxqSrk9FXj+leC971QDfNRZ6OUgeq4PWqn/ACMbcOTvqL/NZeM0CzuurO1wun6x54j/AJHG3wIUPaiHLVB/UL3SOuxcDeNsTU187ZISwNDMveOpJWzA8ZgooSyQG5N9FieB0jgQrDpmkMY08Q1oPmAAVXquUSzOe3gSpLG2aAvVRl6VaT7EVLsUbW3Z2Yla+1+9ZvFXGmx2niohAQb2IUJ9M50mZWBi1OZYZI28XNIHmeCqsMgZM154A3Uwi4soJu42QqsOne+XI6OSPIbHVpBu0+OuitOL43S1lOY2g34hRIKd8brrrbebFtxBoewhkzeB5HwK5eD4w6hdlcLtPJbZ4BIPFV2zYbF4wYY3PDDybM9rDf8AdGmqtv4gw5wzOOvlqoXoso0Cme7/AHfCid6RUFr5QO4B6sd+JHV3K6r2M4+apu5hBDeZ5n9lKgpchzO4qVbS4FHWwmGXzafslcShrZKOUSM/7CkSRh7bFVLLu8xKmkPorzY6Z2SOYSOV8vFXiLaOilZ+ZoehF1zjSSNOi6NPuvndDLJO8PqX2DLuJDddXOcdXG2iiS7TwiZrYwQwcdOPgByWwUZyku4qXt2dmGECg7vahhZx7tyT8LFcibFIX4k2pF8oW8QuERYvndnsvPh8c7JrHtHNcC3wBBWzG8Tjr2NETTp4LzTwmI6ry3k7KTV4i7EtBYTfMVpwLFIqEv3gOq9VEJkAst2kwacYV6E8N7VsZjBB0cNcp8OPwWKrEKeTEG1LL2uCfYjInCMsKrpu6muH14/eVY/xTSdConoT0/sqrvtx/wART8U0nRyehP8ABT92xwmwyCinIEkTLBw1sQSb+WoVelxvLXmpi4GwsVKFPePI5QMbB4tSuc2mkcGk6mOVzAfEgc7Kxs2ioJW3k9xF1FNLK3gV2NlN2s3bipxF+ctIdkzF5cRwLnHUjwXPxHaSPdGKlHHnwt5BbYqQ3zPUm2+2LbiDQ9jgyVvAngR0K42EYy6icQ4XaeK3TwCQeKgEexeNRDsopXtZws2Z7W+4cFa/6/hrxmdx8WhQ/RpRwPxUu3f7vvQ5PSqlwfML5AODM2hdc6lxuRfxXAxjaD0lm5gFm8zzPh4BSYKbIczuKkG39Z2NBO7mWFo8zouVg0O9rY2+N/cts5tGSuVuVoctA11v1srj7BZo/NWDaA7+uig8R8So1NpGXK2VbbKOo3trQdtBIz7THD2jgqljrTBWRVA8vcVLg7TC1VjuSrbNqqRx1Y8PA97HfEKVtPDvadszeX1WqkNnFqs66oS6KwiJdFlLrKJdES6IsXREuiJdES6Il0RERcba/GvQqWScC7mizR1J0HxU/DKP0upbEeB4+S1yvyMLlQFXtDVyydq+pmz3uCJHNDfugGwC+oQ0sMLAyNoA8vmuM6RzjclXPuv2mkrqZwqDmlhcGl/AvaRdpPjyVL2moI4XNljFrroUkhcLFTJVRTUWFhERZRERERERFlERFhVtvsxLJTMhB1e65Hg3VWvZSnzTul6D5qJWO7NuqsHYbDPR6enhPGOJub7xF3fElbaU+l4y6Tk2/wBgsHsQgKVq4qKtXEY7sPhquJj9NvqMkcW6rdA6z1Qgf+i8eDjpFM7KelpbD4Oy+8rFC4V+F5DxAt7l5kG7mv1VwuFtF89kYWOLTyXTBuLrC8IiLKXWUS6IsIiXREuiJdES6IiIsoi5O1GECsppIHG2YaHoRwUzD6s0tQ2UclrkZnaQvzliVH2Mroi9ry02LmG7fevqsEu9jD7EX5HiuK5uU2Vs7mK2lET6eN59Jce0eHC2YAW7p5ho+aqu01JUSN3v+DeX1U2ke0ac1ZSo66CyiIiIiIiLKIiIiLCIiqHFR+k8djg4xQEF/MWjs9w9pyt9pV+oB/T8KMx7xF/foPuufL+ZNl6K88LZoXHmVr2Zpy2F0x4uPwH7r3UO1Dei3lZ1GWCF5c0OBaeBRU7vp2eL4e2aO9EdepaeaqWDSGhrn0j+BOn0+ClVDd5GHhd7YHHvTqGKVxvIz6KX77BbN/mbZ3tKgbR0O4qN40aO+a2UsmZtuikCrqlIiIiLCIiIiIiIiIiIsoi1XYlAM95owWWDwXgFtxcXv1U1mHVL2Ne1hIPBazI0GxKrXeTt+0s9FoZQ4u0klaeA5saftHryHmrPgmAOY/fVTeHAePU/ZQ6iqFsrFU9lc1z1It3U+TE6Q9ZQz+Nrmfmolc3NTSD/APJWyI2cF+i18iXbREREREREWUREWEWEXG2wxkUdJLOeIaQ0dXHQD3roYZRmrqWxDhfXy5rXK/I0lRPcvgjhFJWSayVDrNJ45Qbk+1xPuVk2kqDJIyih8NPHgB7FFpm2BeVcsTMoA6Kz0sDYIWxN4AWWlzsxuvtb15REXJ2hoGzRuDhcEFrvIqsbQ0jgG1cfebx8v2Umnf8A4nmqO2UrHYPib6SY2gmIbc8ASfo3+829qnSBmLYfmHG3uK0i8EtuSuNwsvnUkZjcWu4hdQG4usLysoiIiLCIiIiIvmR4aC48ALk68Oa9NaSbBLr4oauOdofC9sjTza6/w5KXUYdUQGz2la2ysdwK0NqsRNNSyTA2cG93QnU+qLcySs4fSmepZG4aE68vNJH5Wkqg8cwiqjd2teSx0puS83e88Sco4gX9l19LpamneN3T8G9OAXIex41dzXlh1ZS072ydk6oc03AkcI4r8iWtu5wvyJC2TRSytLM2UHpqfedB8VhrmtN7XXNqJi97nm13OLjbh3jfTw1W9jQxoaOWi8E3N1ubOzZKumf9meE+6RqxKM0bh1B+SyzvBfp5/E+a+PSCzyPEruDgsLwsoiIiLKIiIiwsIiKotuqx+KYhFhtOe413fcNQLeu4/dbf2kK94NAzDqJ1ZNxI0+g9pUCd28eGBXNs9hzImMZGLMjaGMHkLe/+qi4DTvqqh1bL1NvM/ZbJiGNDAu0rioiIiIiw5txYrw9jXtLXcCsg2N1Ve9nZD0iIyMH0kYuD9pvRVCilfhNaYJO47gfkfoVKkaJo8w4heG63as1kPo05/wBogFtTrLGODvvN9U+QPNbNo8Lv/qYh5/dYpZv8Cpv/AO/1VNU5YRERERERFlEVWbxP0hSZ6htbI2J7w1sTTo0HTifervgM9NUBtOYhcDUlc+pa9t33XhDusqo3ZoqzKTrdoc0m+tzZy2S7TxNcWOi4acf2XltG46hy96/YyvbGTPibhG3Ul5dlGXW+p5LXFtBBI8Njgu49P+l6NM4DVyge0VY2QNaayaqMdwwujysaDa9i52axsOSsdK14u50YZe17G5PnYW081EkI4XuuVS1jowcrYyTbvOY17m2+yXer81JfGH8b+/59VrDrLxkkLiXONydSV7AAFgsLMLrOaRyc0+4goshfqsuvr1sfeLr5BVgCd4HUruM7oWFHXpERZRERERYRYRRDeRtUKGnLYyO3k7sY+z1eR4cvGy7uBYWayfM8dhup8fD+cloqJd23xXhun2SdTxekTAmon1N+LGHUA+J4n2KfjFW7EaltHT90G3hfmfILVAzdtzu4q1oow0ADkrdS07KeJsTOAUdzi43K+1IXlERERERa9bTCRtufL+i5eK4c2tht/kNQf51W2KTI5URt9s7Nh9S3EaK7bOu4Aeq7ncc2ngufguI7xpo6nvDTX5LNRFY7xin+yO00WIwCaPuvbYSx31jd+bDxBXCxvCHUkmdncPwUmnnDxY8V2lwFJREREREWURV9vo/ubPxG/MKz7Kfqz5KHW+rVgN4DyHyC4Nb69/mVJZ3Qq1304xkhjpWnWQ5nfdb/AFNvirJsrSZpXTn/AB0HmVFrX2bl6qouwdk7SxyZsmblmtmy+dhdXfO3Nlvra/s4Lm2NrrzXpYREW7g9VFFK2SaJ0waQ4Rh4ja4g3GY5XG1+Q4rVMx8jC1rst+dr+7Ua+K9MIBuQv0jgGJ+l00VTkydqwOy5s2XUi2awvw6L5fitI2lqTG038SuxE/O2631zVtWURERFhYREXK2mx+GhgdPMfBrR6z3cmgdfkNVNoKCWtmEUftPIDqV4kkDBcqutisEmxWq/SdcPomu+ij5PI9Ua/Ubx/ePgrXilZHhtOKGl754nmP3PwChxMMrt4/gryoKbKLnifgpeBYX6LHvJB23fAdPuk0mY2HBba760IiIiIiIiIiLm4xhjZmEFoNxYg/WH9VXsZwozf6iDSQfH91Ihly9l3BUTj2DVOCVQrKLWIkhzdbWvqxw6fJe8MxKOviNPUDtjTXn+68TRGI528FZWyu00GIxdrAbOFu0iJ70Z/NvRyrWL4LJSOzs1YfgpcE4eLHiuwuEpCyiLCIsoir7fR/c2fiN+YVn2U/VnyUOt9WrAB0HkPkuDWfqH+ZUlndC/O+8LFvSa6V97tZ9G3pZt7/ElfScFpfR6NjeZ1Pt/ay5NQ/PIV87T0/o8NJSnRwjdUSj9+ciwPiGNaFso376aWXlcMHk3j7ySsSdlob7V4YaB6DWm2ofSWPS7pbrbN+ph/wDf5BGdxy4qlrSiIv0dsB+zaT8IfMr5rtF+ucuvTerCkC4SkIiIsLCIi5e0ePwUMJmqHWHBrRq55+y0cz8uJU2hoJq2XdxDzPIDqVrkkawXKrLCcNqcfqRVVYMdIw91v2v3G9f3n+wK31NRT4JT7iDWU8/qfoFDa107szuCu/CMNbG1tmhrWgBjRoAB4LRguEuc/wBLqdSdQD8z9FsmlAGRq6qtqioiIiIiIiIiIiIiLmYvhLJmuBaDcatPB3/lV3FcHMp9IptJB8f3UiKa3ZdwVIbTbH1OGT+m4aXANJu0cWjmCPrN8Ew3GWTj0asFncNef7rzNTlvbj4KWbG7wYK60MtoKn7DtGSEfYceB/dOvS6gYrs6W3lptR0+y2w1QOjlMSLcfzVSc0tNnCxU0aovKIsIq+30f3Nn4jfmFaNlP1Z8lDrfVqZY0ZPRpOy1f2fd88q5Lsnp35nDNr71vF8mnRUHsps9LU1jI5I3hofmlJBAAabm5PXh7V9ErcQhp6YyBw4aefJcqKJzn2IXjtrX9vWzyDhmyt8m6AL3hkJipWNPG1z5nVYndd5WwykdDSV8bvWbJRX9plP5rDpBJNA5vDt/IL01tmOBUcU9aERF+jtgP2bSfhD5lfNdov1zl16b1YUgXCUhFhYREUV2y27p8PBZftZ7aRNPq35vP1R4cT0XbwvA5605j2WdTz8hz8+Cjy1DWeah2A7LVeLzCtxQubF/w4+BcONg36jPiV3qzE6fDIvRaIXfzPQ/U/JaGROlOeTgrpwnCmxtaA0Na0Wa0aAW8FrwnBXud6TV6k6gH5n7L3LMLZWLqq2qKiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiItaso2yDXj8/A9QuTiWERVgvwfyP3W2OYs8lVW3G7FkxMkFopeOnqu/oVxYMSq8MeIaoXbyP2K3PhZN2mcVGsL22r8McKfEonTRDQOPrtHg8+t5FdaWjocUZnjIv4cVHEkkJsVZOAbS0lcL0szXOtcxuOWVvmw6nzFwqpXYDU02oGZvUKbHUMeuqVxCCDYqQopvF2fmroGxQ5bh4JLjoLLtYHXxUU5kkva3JR6iMyNsFKmcB5D5LlVEgklc8cytzRYWXm+naQ4AAZgQSBbivAeQQeizZVRTbrJ/Sw5729iJM5PFzhfNlt4q7HaeL0fKxpz2tbkueKM57k6LcxbYWrkFbYMHpEsL2a+qIi+9/YQtcOOU8W5a8G7A6+nMhe3QOOa3NR7+ymu6x+8qf8Aiii8Vo9Df4J/ZTXdY/eU/FFF4p6G/wAFb2ylA+no4IJLZ42ZXW4XBPBU3FqtlVUulj4FT4WFjQCuquYti5uOY/TUTc1TM2Po293u+6waldCjwypqz+Uw268vetb5Ws4lVvim3lbiLzT4VC9jToZPrW6l3qxj3lWqDBaPD2b6scCenL3cSoZnfKbMC72xW7JkLhNVfTzk5tdWtJ56+sfEqHV4zU17vR6JpDfjbx5ALayBkfafxVqUdCGanU/ALq4XgcdL+ZJ2n/AeX3WuWYu0HBba760IiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiL5ewEWIuFrlhZK0skFx0KyCQbhcXGdm4qhpa9jXtPJ35FVmpwGSF29onWPT7FSWzgizwqq2i3TWd2lG8xvGoabix/dcOHsXmHaGemduqxh8/wCcVh1K12sZXNi2oxrDTkqozURjm8En2SN194K6RZheIi4tf3FarzRcVIMK3s0UlhOyWB3PTO33jULmVOynOJ3vW1tYOYUqoNpqGf8AU1cDj0Lww+51lxZsArY/8b+S3tqYzzXWY24u3UdRqPguc+iqGd5h9y2h7TzWjWziKWMzZmwlr2l9jZjzly5rcGkZhfqrDsy2JkzzKLOtpf4+1RqkkgW4LbpnBzfo3F7b6OFyD4A8ws7TPikla2MXIGpHySmuGm69HNIFzoOp0+arTaaZ2gafcpOdvVcuv2io4P11VCzw7QE+5typ0OC1svCM+1azPGOai2K716CK4i7SY+AyN97l2KfZSZ3rHALQ6sbyUeftbjOI92ih7CM/XA1t+I8fILpCgwnD9ZXBx8dfgPqte8mk7oXQwLdTnf2tfK6aQ6kAk3Pi46uUSo2kkkO6omeWnyA4L22lA1kKtLBtnY4GBkbGxtH1Wiy8U+BVNU/e1rj5c/2Xp07WizAu3HGGiwFlaaelip2ZIm2CjOcXG5X2pC8oiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiL5ewHQi61ywxytyyNBHisgkahaVRhbHC3wOo9xXBqNm6d5zREsPwW9tS4cdVF8X3eUk9y+BhPVvdKhChxak9S/MPP6Fey+F/eCiGJbnIDfI6RnmLhehjmIwaTRHzt9eC8+jxO7pXEduknjN4KnKfC7T/pstrNrIzo+MryaM8isjYPF26MrpbeE0o/7ls/E1EeMfwCeiyf7k//AATF3etXS28ZpT/3IdpaIcI/gPsnosn+5BumqJP19UXeZc7+Yla3bWRtHYjT0M8yuxhu5ynFs7pH+Wg+C0HaCvn9RF8CV69GjHeKmGD7vaSCxZTsB+07vH4ryaXGav1rso8/oF6DoWcApTBhbW/0GgUqn2YhbrM4uPuC8uqSeC3I4w31QArBBSwwNyxNAHgtDnF3Ffa3ryiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiwUWnWKv4rzW+Jc1/FUyXipgRq8s4oV0KTkrZhXJRZVvK0hRkWUREREREREREREREREREREREX//2Q==" class="pimg">
             <span class="date">13:00 - 07/23/1993</span>
            <span class="msg"><span class="username">tink</span><span class="text">HI</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="snd-msg" />
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent `flex` with `align-items: center`, then use `order` to make the `.date` that element last visually, and use `margin-left: auto` to push it to the right.

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #cbox {
            border: 1px black solid;
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 95%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;

        }
        .message {
            min-height: 50px;
            max-height: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 98.9%;
            border: 1px black solid;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #snd-msg {
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 3%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .pimg {
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
            border: 1px black dashed;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
        .username {
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            text-decoration: underline;

        }
        .date {
            color: gray;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: 10px;
            order: 1;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="cbox">
        <div class="message" name="tink" id="mid">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="pimg">
             <span class="date">13:00 - 07/23/1993</span>
            <span class="msg"><span class="username">tink</span><span class="text">HI</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="snd-msg" />
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer adds a few lines and hopefully solves the issue with flexbox. Here it is:

https://codepen.io/laurenglegg/pen/LjexXN

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="cbox">
        <div class="message" name="tink" id="mid">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="pimg">
             <div>
                <span class="date">13:00 - 07/23/1993</span>
                <span class="msg"><span class="username">tink</span>
                <span class="text">HI</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="snd-msg" />
</div>
</body>

 html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #cbox {
            border: 1px black solid;
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 95%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;

        }
        .message {
            min-height: 50px;
            max-height: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 98.9%;
            border: 1px black solid;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #snd-msg {
            width: 100.0%;
            height: 3%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .pimg {
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
            border: 1px black dashed;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
        .username {
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            text-decoration: underline;

        }
        .date {
            position: absolute;
            color: gray;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            right: 0;
        }
```